# Child LayoutParams are null before measuring in Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView. When inflating the xml provided the childView LayoutParameters are null. Therefore I have to apply new LayoutParameters. This isn't good because in my xml template there are margins set. If I apply new LayoutParameters then I lose the MarginLayoutParameters. Then when I come to onMeasure my custom ViewGroup I only have the childs height to go by and no extra margin space on the bottom.

Why are the child LayoutParams null when I have specified wrap_content and a margin?

list_item.axml
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="2" />
</LinearLayout>`

this is how the above xml is inflated
`View child =     LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_item,null);`

then I check its layoutParams

`if (child.getLayoutParams () == null)`

Comment: custom ViewGroup?  i don't see any...

Comment: ViewGroup customisation is irrelevant. An override of onLayout() and onMeasure() will suffice. Inflate this xml and before measuring there's no layoutParams. I need to know how to either get the amount of margin on the child or whether the childs measuredHeight incorporates its own margin space.

Comment: you should add your code of the measurement at least. but my guess is, that you are casting to the wrong LayoutParameters. check your imports

Comment: when inflating pass a parent ViewGroup

Comment: Edited with bleedings requests. As I was posting this I was just realising that I was passing in null as the parent. I'm too used to doing this from previous tutorials.

Comment: an advice: better rely on official documentation than on web tutorials

Comment: This was from google I/O conference. They advise not to pass in a parent when inflating a view in Adapter getView()

Comment: but you dont have to add the inflated `View` to the `root` parent : see the third param of `inflate` method